# Number of solutions to a difference of squares congruence mod p

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How many solutions (ordered pairs) are there for the congruence $$x^2-y^2\equiv a (modp)$$ if p is and odd prime and doesn't divide a?

My first attempt was factorizing the difference. I know p divides $(x+y)(x-y)-a$ but it doesn't divide a, so it cannot divide $x+y$ nor $x-y$... that cuts down the possibilities, but only gets me so far.

Answer (score 1):

The factorization idea works.

Let $x+y\equiv t\pmod{p}$, where $1\le t\le p-1$. Then $x^2-y^2\equiv a\pmod{p}$ if and only if $x-y\equiv t^{-1}a\pmod{p}$.

So for fixed $t$, $(x,y)$ is a solution if and only if $x\equiv 2^{-1}(t+t^{-1}a)\pmod{p}$, and $y\equiv 2^{-1}(t-t^{-1}a)$. It follows that our  congruence has $p-1$ solutions.